# Javascript: Out of scope?

Tags: javascript

Re-Edited:
I went over to W3schools and played around in there javascript editor window to see what was going on. Here is a shorter script.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var eType = document.getElementById("Type")
</script>
<select class="field select addr" id="Type"> 
        <option value="Type:L" selected="selected">Location</option>
        <option value="Type:C">Corporate</option>
        <option value="Type:R">Remittama</option>
        <option value="Type:M">Mailing</option>
        </select>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(eType);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I did what ThiefMaster suggested on how to get the element by not using the .text or .value but as you can see if you run this code I still get a null at this step of the process. From what I can see and many suggestions I am doing this correctly. I know I must be missing something. Can anyone see it?

Comment: You don't want to be using `document.write()` after the document has finished loading. I'd suggest adding the hidden input as part of your initial markup and just set its value from JS. Or use [`.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).

Comment: w3schools is not so great.  check out http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the element before you've actually put it on the page. Fix the order, and don't use document.write.

```
<html>
<body>

<select class="field select addr" id="Type"> 
        <option value="Type:L" selected="selected">Location</option>
        <option value="Type:C">Corporate</option>
        <option value="Type:R">Remittama</option>
        <option value="Type:M">Mailing</option>
        </select>
<script type="text/javascript">
var eType = document.getElementById("Type")
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(eType));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second code block is almost correct; you need to use the select element itself instead of its (non-existent) value:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("Type");
var type = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/nw3nN/

If you had [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) available you could drastically reduce the amount of code necessary:

```
var type = $('#Type').val();
```